# Tool ability only being able to be used once?

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I have a tool that allows the player to dash, yet for some reason the cooldown doesnt seem to work correctly. Does anyone know why the player can't use the ability again?

```
-- Locals --
local Tool = script.Parent
local Cooldown = false
local mouse=game.Players.LocalPlayer:GetMouse()
local sound=Instance.new("Sound")
-- Main Script --
mouse.KeyDown:Connect(function(key)
    if key=="e" then
        if Cooldown == false then
            Cooldown = true
            sound.Parent=Tool.Handle
            sound.Volume=3
            sound.SoundId="rbxassetid://9079020013"
            sound:Play()
            game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 60
            wait(.5)
            sound:Destroy()
            game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
            wait(5)
            Cooldown = false
        end
    end
end)
```

The goal is for the player to have an E ability that makes them dash, play a sound effect, then stop after half a second. Then, 5 seconds later, the player could do it again. All of this happened, except the player wasnt able to use the ability again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this yet, a tool can be activated.

```
script.Parent.activated:Connect(function()
    local sound=Instance.new("Sound")
    if Cooldown == false then
        Cooldown = true
        sound.Parent=Tool.Handle
        sound.Volume=3
        sound.SoundId="rbxassetid://9079020013"
        sound:Play()
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 60
        wait()
        sound:Destroy()
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
        wait(5)
        Cooldown = false
    end
end)
```

Comment: Or if you want to blind E as , you should be using UserInputService, not tool. Answer me if you can.

Comment: Don't use comments on your answer to start a conversation. You should comment on the question if you need clarification or want to make a suggestion.

Comment: yes, i have tried to activate the tool. I want the player to use the tool's ability to dash, because i already have the tool being activated in another script.